# How to make annotation for foreign key in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-annotate

I need to replace `_points` property by annotation so that I have the opportunity to sort entries in the Django admin panel by this value.

My model:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    inviter = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def _points(self):
        res = CustomUser.objects.filter(inviter_id=self.id).count()
        return res
```

My admin:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['created', 'updated']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(CustomUserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.annotate(points=(HOW TO CALCULATE _points HERE?).order_by('points')
        return qs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opposite way of the `inviter` relation is the `customuser`, so you can implement this as:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['created', 'updated']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).annotate(
            points=Count('customuser')
        ).order_by('-points')
```

It might however make more sense to rename the [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) of your `inviter` to `invitees`:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    inviter = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        related_name='invitees',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    @property
    def _points(self):
        return self.invitees.count()
```

then we thus count this as:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['created', 'updated']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).annotate(
            points=Count('invitees')
        ).order_by('-points')
```